# Converting Data Structure in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm wondering how to convert the following data structure in Ansible:

```
app_map:
  nuc:
    - homer
    - librespeed
  raspi:
    - unifi
```

Converted to:

```
new_app_map:
  homer: nuc
  librespeed: nuc
  unifi: raspi
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What have you already tried, and what error is it producing for you?

Answer (score 1):

The task below does the job

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      new_app_map: "{{ new_app_map|default({})|combine({item.1: item.0.key}) }}"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ app_map|dict2items }}"
      - value
```